# Error while swapping values

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

While swapping the maximum value of a list with the minimum value of other list, SyntaxError: can't assign to function call is raised.Here both lists have integer values.

Line that is showing error:

```
l1.index(max(l1)),l2.index(min(l2))=l2.index(min(l2)),l1.index(max(l1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test this code :

```
l1=[2,6]
l2=[1,3]
l1[l1.index(max(l1))],l2[l2.index(min(l2))]=l2[l2.index(min(l2))],l1[l1.index(max(l1))]
```

after run :

```
l1= [2, 1]
l2= [6, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It is still not clear to me that why syntax error was raised in the above line! Can you help me out with that?

Comment: I hope I can explain well.
Because l1.index (max (l1)) returns a number as an output and does not refer to any element of the list.
Therefore, you should change l1.index (max (l1)) to l1 [l1.index (max (l1))].

Comment: So basically i was trying to swap two constants and not the actual values. Well that was pretty silly!  Thanks once again.